# OpenSSL BIO writing partial file

Tags: c, openssl

I'm trying to use openssl bio to perform FTP STOR operation. Most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes it only sends partial data. So the logic goes like this:

```
1. authentication and passive mode selection
2. open data connection
3. write data
4. QUIT
```

All operations should be performed synchronously. The data writing function does this:

```
while (written < toWrite && n > 0) {
    n = BIO_write(bio, message.c_str() + written, toWrite - written);
    written += n;
}
```

After this loop, written == toWrite and n > 0, so it would indicate that the write was completed successfully. However, the file is truncated. When I view the operation in wireshark, I can notice that QUIT operation is sent right after the first chunk of data is transferred. Client also continues sending some data chunks after QUIT command. Does anyone have a clue how that is possible?

EDIT: If there's a short delay (e.g. sleep) between writing data and QUIT, it works perfectly.

Comment: Looks like the underlying socket is non-blocking and the BIO_Write is returning 0 (which is something valid in non-blocking socket scenario), please provide the socket creation call and check that in cases where n == 0, BIO_should_retry returns true.

Comment: I'm using a blocking BIO. The first thing I tried was to add a check after that loop, if (BIO_should_retry(bio)), and set a breakpoint within. It never reaches that line. Also, after the loop, bio->flags == 0.

Comment: Sounds weird... check if you have activated SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE option.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not currently using SSL (the same BIO api is used for both secure and non-secure connection). Is there an equivalent option for BIO with no ssl context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. I did not wait for the response on control socket between closing the data connection and sending QUIT. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343022/dont-always-get-a-226-transfer-ok-at-the-end-of-an-ftp-upload) was helpful for finding the answer.